# AngularJS integration with Vaadin

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, vaadin, vaadin7

I have used **jquery** integration with **[vaadin](https://vaadin.com/)** many times inside custom components. I wanna see an example of **angularjs** integration with vaadin.

Additionally need to know **[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)** is working with **IE9**.

Answer (score 1):

you can check out https://github.com/akquinet/vaangular/tree/master/vaangular-demo for an example of how 2 integrate Vaadin and AngularJS...

The main thing that happens is creating a $scope for AngularJS that is wired up with vaadin. There is one essential challenge: the JavaScript invoked by vaadin is outside any AngularJS dependency injection or scope management. Meanwhile, all code you write for AngularJS is obviously inside dependency injection and scope management.

Furthermore, AngularJS assumes (at least per se) that the page's HTML is parsed once and wired up to AngularJS. With vaadin, however, the page's HTML is just some proxy to fire up vaadin, and there is nothing to wire up. Even more so, the part with AngularJS in it might be added to a vaadin UI a considerable amount of time after the application was started.

So, what is needed is an approach to create some new AngularJS-wired-up DOM and Controller on demand from outside AngularJS dependency management / scoping magic.

given a module 'innerModuleName' defined with angular.module, vaangular achieves this (in bespoke NgTemplate.js) in two steps:

First, a scope within AngularJS is created via

```
angular.injector([ 'ng', innerModuleName ]).invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
```

Second, the scope (called scpe) and DOM are brought together via

```
var connectorElement = angular.element(connector.getElement());
var cmp = $compile(templateElement);
scpe = $rootScope.$new(false);
cmp(scpe);
scpe.$digest();
connectorElement.append(templateElement);
```

At the end of this process, we have a new part of the DOM wired up to a new controller.

The point is that now, you can have the Vaadin Connector inside angularJS

Comment: Please don't post links only. Add the important stuff to your answer.

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the link which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the link goes down, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much to answer this question.

Comment: If this answer is what you wanrted, please award it as the answer.